# Find the root of the git repository where the file lives

Tags: python, git

When working in Python (e.g. running a script), how can I find the path of the root of the git repository where the script lives?

So far I know I can get the current path with:

```
path_to_containing_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

How can I then find out where the git repository lives?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the GitPython module http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

```
pip install gitpython
```

Assume you have a local Git repo at `/path/to/.git`. The below example receives `/path/to/your/file` as input, it correctly returns the Git root as `/path/to/`.

```
import git

def get_git_root(path):

        git_repo = git.Repo(path, search_parent_directories=True)
        git_root = git_repo.git.rev_parse("--show-toplevel")
        print git_root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_git_root("/path/to/your/file")
```

Comment: This one did the trick for me. Useful to use `os.getcwd()` instead of `"/path/to/your/file"` when calling this function. Thanks.

Comment: Once you have the repo you can just use `git_repo.working_dir`

Answer (score 45):

The [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=working_tree_dir#git.repo.base.Repo.working_tree_dir) module provides this attribute right out-of-the-box for you:

```
import git

repo = git.Repo('.', search_parent_directories=True)
repo.working_tree_dir
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it doesn't rely on the shell which doesn't work well across platforms.

Comment: If you want to support bare repositories, use `working_dir` instead.

Answer (score 30):

Looking for a `.git` directory will not work in all cases. The correct git command is:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Comment: Note to Future Self: `repo_dir = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @RyneEverett thanks for that, FYI it threw `LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8` for me in 2.7.6, I had to remove the `.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Just wondering, in what cases would looking for a `.git` directory not work?

Comment: @danodonovan `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @danodonovan you can have a ``.git`` file not a directory if you have a worktree checkout.

Comment: Note: This does not work when inside a submodule, it will show the submodule root

Comment: Submodule root is parent project, right?

Answer (score 11):

Without any external libraries:

```
import subprocess

def getGitRoot():
    return subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I turned this answer into a one-function-python package, which is available via pip (`pip install git_root`) and conda (`conda install -c conda-forge git_root`): see https://github.com/jtilly/git_root @rouble I hope this is okay with you!

Answer (score 8):

I just wrote a small python module for this task:
https://github.com/MaxNoe/python-gitpath

Install with `pip install git+https://github.com/maxnoe/python-gitpath`

Usage:

```
import gitpath

print(gitpath.root())
print(gitpath.abspath('myfile.txt'))
```

`gitpath.abspath(relative_path)` will return the absolute path on your machine 
for a path given relative to the root of the git repository.

The code to get the root is partially derived from Ryne Everetts comment:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def root():
    ''' returns the absolute path of the repository root '''
    try:
        base = check_output('git rev-parse --show-toplevel', shell=True)
    except CalledProcessError:
        raise IOError('Current working directory is not a git repository')
    return base.decode('utf-8').strip()
```

The caching makes the second call to `root()` ca. 3500 times faster (measured with `ipython` and `%%timeit`)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948875/python-git-module-invalid-git-repository-error/39299502#39299502

Comment: Deserves to be on pypi!

Comment: As @CivFan pointed out - GitPython now provides this with Reop(...,search_parent_directories)

Comment: Note: This does not work from a submodule

Answer (score 7):

I found the other answers too confusing for the task so I made this function to solve the issue. Basically, it loops through the parent directories of the given path and returns the first one that contains ".git" directory. If none found, None is returned.

```
from pathlib import Path

def find_repo(path):
    "Find repository root from the path's parents"
    for path in Path(path).parents:
        # Check whether "path/.git" exists and is a directory
        git_dir = path / ".git"
        if git_dir.is_dir():
            return path

# Find the repo root where the script is
find_repo(__file__)
```

Pathlib is part of the standard library (Python 3) so there is no extra dependencies. Gitpython is overkill if this is the only thing you need from it.

Answer (score 6):

This function is generic (not depending on external module or calling `git` command).
It searches up from a given path to find the first one containing a `.git` directory.

```py
def find_vcs_root(test, dirs=(".git",), default=None):
    import os
    prev, test = None, os.path.abspath(test)
    while prev != test:
        if any(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(test, d)) for d in dirs):
            return test
        prev, test = test, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(test, os.pardir))
    return default
```

Example use:

```py
import os
print(find_vcs_root(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Or check for other version control:

```py
import os
print(find_vcs_root(os.path.dirname(__file__)), dirs=(".hg", ".git", ".svn"))
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for since I can't install packages where I run my scripts

Comment: Great. easy implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about python, but I think you could keep going down a directory with

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir, '..'))
```

Until you detect a `.git` directory (`os.walk` might help)

Comment: Thanks, but the file is deep inside the git repository, so the walk (at least as it is) would fail, and simply going up many levels and running the walk again is not guaranteed to find the closest `.git` ancestor.

Comment: You'll have to walk from the bottom and up. Look for a .git directory in the current directory, if not chop off the last directory component and try again. Do so recursively until you hit a boundary (e.g. the file system's root directory)