# Python git module Invalid git repository error

Tags: python, git

I have a script that is placed in a folder structure as such:

`~/wofc/folder1/folder2/script.py`

`script.py` uses the git module to go some tasks. However when I run the script from outside of `folder2` i.e. when I have `cd` into `folder1` i run `python folder2/script.py arg1 arg2` I get the `raise InvalidGitRepositoryError(epath)` error. The script runs fine when I run it from inside `folder2` i.e. `cd` into `folder2` and run `python script.py arg1 arg2`. Below is the relevant code snippet. Can You please let me know what is the issue?

```
    git = Repo('{}/..'.format(os.getcwd())).git
    git.checkout('master')
    git.pull()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Repo('{}/..'.format(os.getcwd())).git`, use `os.path.abspath`:

```
git = Repo(os.path.abspath('{}/..'.format(os.getcwd())).git
git.checkout('master')
git.pull()
```

Comment: gives the same issue I am currently facing

Answer (score 1):

To run `git commands`, the current folder should be a `git repo`.

`.git` repo should be present to execute git commands.

That is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `os.getcwd()` which returns the current working directory. If you stand just outside `folder2` this function will return `~/wofc/folder1`.

You should swap it for something like:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

For example like this:

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
git = Repo('{}/..'.format(path)).git
git.checkout('master')
git.pull()
```

Comment: wrong answer, the repo directory is not in the same path!

Answer (score 0):

As user1846747 said, gitPython requires a Repo object to run a git command.

This is a classic bootstrap issue (chicken and egg problem): "how can I run a git command running gitPython to find where the Repo root is, when I need to know where the root is to create a Repo object to run a git command?"

@MaxNoe solved this in [Find the root of the git repository where the file lives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081209/find-the-root-of-the-git-repository-where-the-file-lives) with his python-gitpath project httpsgithub.com/MaxNoe/python-gitpath