# In Python, how to get the caller's method's full git path in the called method?

Tags: python, frame

I am using following [answer related to In Python, how do I obtain the current frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140513/2402577)

> ```
> def WHERE( back = 0 ):
>    frame = sys._getframe( back + 1 )
>    return "%s/%s %s()" % ( os.path.basename( frame.f_code.co_filename ), 
>                            frame.f_lineno, frame.f_code.co_name )
> ```

---

If the function(`doo.py`) call is made from `/home/user/project/function.py`; it `WHERE(1)` prints
`./function.py`

`/home/user/project/test/doo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import utils
def doo():
    print(utils.WHERE(1))
```

---

`/home/user/project/test/function.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from test.doo import doo

doo()
```

---

```
$ /home/user/project/test/function.py
function.py:5 <module>()
```

---

At this point instead of printing the filename (ex: `foo.py`); is it possible to return its full path `test/function.py` from the root of the git repo?

Comment: Check `gitpython` out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081209/find-the-root-of-the-git-repository-where-the-file-lives

Comment: @MZ I am getting only the filename, since I don't know its parent folder, I cannot make the git base path check, files with same names could exist under sub-folders